# pandas.read_html returning empty table

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read the weapons table in [this page](https://ps2.fisu.pw/player/?name=nixogimpo&show=weapons) and convert it into a Pandas DataFrame.

I am trying with `pandas.read_html()` function but it returns only the table header and only the first column title is returned. I also tested with other stuff like BeautifulSoup with no results.
The problem is similar to the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68943588/pandas-read-html-only-getting-header-of-html-table), except for the fact that the proposed solution (using the flavor input of `pandas.read_html()`) does not work in my case.

Here is my code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import ssl
#----#
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
#----#
my_url = 'https://ps2.fisu.pw/player/?name=nixogimpo&show=weapons'
#----#
my_html = urlopen(my_url, context=ctx).read()
#----#
df = pd.read_html(str(my_html)) # flavor = "html5lib", "bs4", "lxml" does not fix
#----the table i need is the one with index 2
print(df[2])
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Weapon]
Index: []
```

Comment: Looks like the data is loaded dynamically. You could try [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428898/11380795)

Comment: thanks for the hint, i'll take a look at it and see what i can get

Comment: by using the code found in your link i managed to read my table, many thanks @RJAdriaansen  !!!